# Diagnosing Errors in Dataproc Create Cluster operation (Java library)

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataproc

When attempting to create a cluster using Google Dataproc, the result appears to initially return successfully, but then a subsequent "get" for the cluster informs me that the cluster went immediately from "Creating" to "Error" state. Unfortunately, attempting to invoke the Diagnostics call did not seem to help.

Here is what I am doing (some liberty has been taken to present the code with hard-coded strings instead of values obtained either via api or through configuration properties):

```
String projectId = "wide-isotope-147019";
String region = "us-central1-f"
GceClusterConfig computeEngineConfig = new GceClusterConfig();
computeEngineConfig.setZoneUri(
    String.format(ZONE_URI_FORMAT, config.getProjectid(),
                  config.getRegion())
List<String> tagList = new ArrayList<>();
tagList.add("ClusterName: mrfoo");
computeEngineConfig.setTags(tagList);

String machineType = String.format(MACHINE_TYPE_URI_FORMAT,
    projectId, region, "n1-standard-1");
InstanceGroupConfig masterConfig = new InstanceGroupConfig();
masterConfig.setMachineTypeUri(machineType)
            .setNumInstances(1);
InstanceGroupConfig workerConfig = new InstanceGroupConfig();
workerConfig.setMachineTypeUri(machineType)
            .setNumInstances(1);
ClusterConfig clusterConfig = new ClusterConfig();
clusterConfig.setMasterConfig(masterConfig);
clusterConfig.setWorkerConfig(workerConfig);
List<NodeInitializationAction> installActions = new ArrayList<>();
// no init actions yet. want to get basics working first.
clusterConfig.setInitializationActions(installActions);
Cluster cluster = new Cluster();
cluster.setProjectId();
cluster.setConfig(clusterConfig);
cluster.setClusterName("mrfoo");

Dataproc.Projects.Regions.Clusters.Create createOp = null;
Operation result = null;
try {
    createOp = dataproc.projects().regions().clusters()
                       .create(projectId, "global", cluster);
    createOp.setBearerToken(...);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  // handle ...
}

try {
    result = createOp.execute();
} catch (IOExceptions ex) {
   // handle.
}

return result;
```

The above generates a "reasonable" result without error. However, later, when I do a get operation:

```
Dataproc.Projects.RegoinsClsuters.Get getOp = null;
Cluster result = null;
try {
    getOp = dataproc.projects().regions().clusters()
           .get("wide-isotope-147019", "global", "mrfoo");
    getOp.setBearerToken(...);
} catch (IOException ioEx) {
  ...
}
try {
   result = getOp.execute();
} catch (IOException ioEx) {
    ...
}
```

The process does not generate errors, but it tells us that the state of the Cluster is: (Sorry for the long dump. See the very end where it shows the history as creating but the current status as ERROR).

```
{"clusterName":"mrfoo","clusterUuid":"<id string>","config":
    {"configBucket":"dataproc-<idstring>",
     "gceClusterConfig":"projectId":"wide-isotope-147019",
    <lots of stuff deleted>
  "status":{"state":"ERROR",
            "stateStartTime":"2016-12-13T00:27:11.143Z"},
   "statusHistory":[
      {"state":"CREATING",
       "stateStartTime":"2016-12-13T00:27:09.947Z"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general pattern for creating a Dataproc cluster is:

```
Operaiton op = createCluster(...);
while(!op.getDone()) {
    sleep(10);
    op = getOperation(op.getName());
}

if (op.hasError()) {
   // Display op.getError(); 
}
```

From looking at logs, in this particular case, I can say that the issue is that Compute Engine is rejecting the instance tags being passed as they do not match Compute Engine's regex for valid tags: `'(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)'`. I've filed a bug so that Dataproc will validate instance tags sooner and raise the error immediately when you attempt to create a cluster instead of setting the error on the operation.

Comment: Are the logs available to me? Can I view them? (FWIW, I am the same "Bill Province," but this is my personal account, and the other is my account for work. I haven't tried linking the accounts yet...). Really, what I want is to be able to properly diagnose these issues, and access to the logs would go a long way in that direction.

Comment: Assuming that the cluster create call ended with an HTTP 200 OK status,  error information will be attached to the Operation. So after polling the operation waiting for it to be complete, you can check to see if there is an error present and if so, display it.

Comment: Alright, I will try that when I get back into the office tomorrow morning. Thanks, Angus. If this works well (which, of course, it should), I will mark the answer accepted.

Comment: Just to be clear, you reference "createCluster(...)" and "getOperation(op.getName())", but I do not see methods with those names in the published APIs. For createCluster(...), I presume you mean the same thing as what I have: dataproc....clusters().create(...) and then dataproc...operations().get(op.getName()) for the second operation. Is this correct? It looks like I do a dataproc....clusters().get(...) instead. Do I have this right? Note that polling in the API here is bad because I want to give our user progress on the creation process.

Comment: You are correct on createCluster and getOperation being stand-ins for the methods you've identified in Java.

Comment: Finally, I found the @##%$OI* error! You mentioned the "tag" but I did not realize that the problem was where I added "ClusterName: mrfoo" as a "tag". I thought you were referring to the cluster name itself! Only when I got the full error information was I able to figure this out. Thanks for your help...